# How to get value from pop up form to mainform in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

In a Purchase management flow, I have a orderForm and CustomerForm. There is a 'CustDetails' button in orderForm. If I click it, then CustomerForm should open as pop up. I can verifty the customer fields and click 'Verified' button in the CustomerForm.

Once verified, I need to change the status of 'CustDetailCheck' field (of that Orderid) in orderTable to 'Verified'.

I dont know how to bring the values of CustomerForm to OrderForm object, so that I can update the order record in OrderTable. Someone pls help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide a control called `txtCustDetailCheck` with a control source of `CustDetailCheck` on the `orderForm` form.  Then when you click on the verified button of the `CustomerForm` form, you can access the `txtCustDetailCheck` control on the `orderForm` and set its value.  The VBA for when you click on the **Verified** button might look like the following:

```
Private Sub cmdVerified_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err_MyError

  Forms!orderForm.txtCustDetailCheck = True
  DoCmd.Close

Exit_MyError:
  Exit Sub
Err_MyError:
  MsgBox Err.Description
  Resume Exit_MyError
End Sub
```